# Did Web Applications got Pimped?

Tags: support, notifications

On 09-02-2013 20.15 CEST the website was only available in a read-only modus. Did we get a new style, rounded corners?

Is meta the place to make those announcements in advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may have been small changes, though I am not seeing them. The read-only was Stack Exchange wide to handle a data change.

```
17:00 UTC Saturday
A final go/no-go decision will be made with the latest info from Internap
Careers ads will dissapear from Stack Overflow
Read-only mode engaged for Q&A Sites + Careers
All live cache layer data will be persisted
Final database saves will be completed, then locked in read-only mode
CDN will be re-pointed to New York
Final transaction logs moved to New York and restored
New York databases recovered and added to AlwaysOn Availability Groups, and brought out of read-only mode
DNS changeover to our New York IPs
Here’s what you should expect to see while browsing the sites:

15:00 UTC Saturday
A banner pointing to this blog post will appear on the main Q&A sites
17:00 UTC Saturday
All sites (excluding chat) will enter a read-only mode
17:30 UTC - Soon™ after that Saturday
You’ll be pointed to our New York data center, the sites should be back to normal
```

http://stackstatus.net/

Comment: Thanks for the info.